# A proper way to bundle realm file using Swift

Tags: ios, swift, realm

I've tried to bundle my pre-populated `Realm` file with my app. I copied if and add the copy bundle resources area in Build Phase. But every time started the app, I can't pull the data. When I look at the file my app has created on the device, the classes are there they are empty.

Here's how I fetch the objects

```
var allTrees: Results<trees>?
allTrees = realm.objects(trees.self)
print(allTrees?.count ?? 0) // always zero
```

My `AppDelegate` setup

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    application.statusBarStyle = .lightContent

    let bundlePath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "default", ofType: ".realm")
    let destPath = Realm.Configuration.defaultConfiguration.fileURL?.path
    let fileManager = FileManager.default

    if fileManager.fileExists(atPath: destPath!) {
        //File exist, do nothing
        print(destPath ?? "if loop")
    } else {
        do {
            //Copy file from bundle to Realm default path
            try fileManager.copyItem(atPath: bundlePath!, toPath: destPath!)
        } catch {
            print(error)
        }
    }

    return true
}
```

My model class

```
class trees: Object {
    @objc dynamic var turkishName = ""
    @objc dynamic var latinName = ""
    @objc dynamic var seedTpye = true
    @objc dynamic var leafType = true
    @objc dynamic var botanicProperties = ""
    @objc dynamic var spreadingArea = ""
}
```